# Make a div purposefully overflow by 32px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div that is styled height:100%. I would like the height to be 100% of the browser window, plus an additional 32px at the bottom, which will be cut off (along with its content). Is this possible? I searched, but it seems most people try to avoid this, not create it. A pure CSS solution would be preferable, but I'll try javascript or jquery if it's the only way.

Thanks in advance!

Clarification: There will be content within the div that I am trying to crop off, about 32px worth. So adding padding or any kind of blank space isn't quite what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that if there is more than 32px of overflowing content, a scrollbar should appear?

Comment: Not quite, I will hide the scrollbar and just let the overflowing content get cropped off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @Steve's answer you can set a height implicitly with `position: absolute` and setting both `top` and `bottom` values. In this case:

HTML:

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body { height: 100%; }

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -32px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/qpvum/

Comment: Brent, this worked perfectly! Thanks so much, thanks to Steve as well for the inspiration.

Comment: should have a parent that is relative, for other scenarios

Answer (score 6):

Just make a 100% height `div` the usual way, and add `padding-bottom: 32px;` to it.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/zbp7U/

With some actual content: http://jsfiddle.net/zbp7U/1/

Comment: For some reason I can't read something else then OP meaning a body with `overflow: hidden;`. ;)

Comment: Maybe I should clarify, there will be specific content contained in the div that I want cropped off. the padding-bottom: 32px will just add blank space. Thanks though.

Comment: @Scott Chandler: Did you check the second demo? That one has content. If that's also no good, then you should clarify further.

Comment: @thirtydot I didn't understand your demo at first, but I just looked at it again and I see what you did. I'm not sure if that would work in my case since the content would need to stretch across the entire div, not just the part that's cut off. But it worked out with another suggestion, thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility in addition to the padding option...

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

.customBox { height: 100%; position: absolute; }

.customBox .overflowFooter { position: absolute; bottom: -32px; height: 100px; }
```

(assuming your content box has class="customBox", and you have a div inside of that with class="overflowFooter")

The above option would give you a standard 100% height box, but adds an additional "footer" piece, which is manually positioned such that the bottom of that content is 32px below the main content, but whose height is 100px.

I'm not really exactly sure what you're going for here...

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks. As I just mentioned above (I'll see if I can add it to my original comment), is that I will have content in the div that I want cropped off by the -32px. I'm not sure if that will work with you method? Sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can go beyond 100%

```
height: 110%;
```

Comment: It's impossible to use %s to specify px. If he wants exactly 32px, this won't work as the extra 10% could be 20px or 200px.